# Liquid faux columns with a border

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a 2-column HTML5 interface (backwards compatibility is not important, all users will be using latest Chrome/FF), with a sidebar on the left and a main content area on the right.

I want the sidebar to have a background color as well as a right border (something like the OS X Finder sidebar). I want that background and border to extend to the bottom of the page, even if the page content isn't enough to extend the page to that size. I also want the sidebar to be set to a percentage, rather than a set amount of pixels.

Normally, I'd go with faux columns, or even liquid faux columns in this case. However I want to have a border to the right of the column, and I'm not sure if/how that's possible.

Ideally, I could do all this without images/faux columns at all. Is there a CSS3/HTML5 feature that will allow for that (as I said, backwards compatibility is not a problem)? If not, are there any other solutions to this besides making the sidebar a fixed size?

Comment: "All users will be using latest Chrome/FF" - I want your users!

Answer (score 0):

I think this demonstrates what you're looking for. If you have any questions about how this example works, don't hesitate to ask! :)

http://www.thechoppr.com/2009/02/09/2-column-fluid-layout-100-height-with-leftright-sidebar

Answer (score -1):

Umm... that ?

```
<style type="text/css">
  #left
  { height:100%;
    width:25%;
    min-width: 100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    border-right:solid 3px orange;
  }
</style>
<div id="left">menu</div>
<div id="right">contents</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with that is the column will only be as high as is necessary for the content in it. I want the column background to span the entire height of the page.

Comment: height:100% only works if every ancestor of the selected element also has a set height (even html & body).

Answer (score -1):

You can use some jQuery:

```
var sidebar_height = 0;
var content_height = 0;

sidebar_height = $("#sidebar").height();
content_height = $("#content").height();
if(sidebar_height > content_height){
    $("#content").css("height", sidebar_height);
} else {
    $("#sidebar").css("height", content_height);
}
```